Invalid input syntax error when importing CSV file into PGAdmin4
I am trying to import a csv file into PGAdmin 4. I think the error I am receiving is related to null values (The value at line 1703 was originally not a proper date). Nulls should be acceptable in this column, in that I did not explicitly click "Not null" when setting up the table. I've tried using the "copy" method and deleting the values from the original file with no luck. Here is the error message in case my image does not appear:
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: ""
CONTEXT: COPY Songs, line 1703, column Release_Date: ""

The docs are a good place to start COPY: NULL Specifies the string that represents a null value. The default is \N (backslash-N) in text format, and an unquoted empty string in CSV format. You have quoted empty strings and this "" will not validate as a date string.
